# Want to zip all the contents(files/folders) inside 4 different folders which are present inside a parent folder

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I want to zip all the contents, (folders/files), present inside `4` different folders, and want to keep the generated `4` different `.zip` files with the same name as their corresponding parent folder.

For example, under location `D:\test\pk` I have `4` folders under `pk` folder:

```
knomBk-2.4-1
knomBk-2.3-1
knomBk-2.5-1
knomBk-2.6-1
```

Inside all of these four folders I have a similar set of contents, (files/folders). I want to zip all the contents in all these four folders one by one and copy over the resultant `4` `.zip` files to a location on my `D:` drive.

So I would be getting something like:

```
D:\outputzipfiles\knomBk-2.4-1.zip
D:\outputzipfiles\knomBk-2.3-1.zip
D:\outputzipfiles\knomBk-2.5-1.zip
D:\outputzipfiles\knomBk-2.6-1.zip
```

How can I do it?

I have tried the `for %a in (directory) do {command..}` loop command like:

```
 D:\test\pk>  FOR %a in (`DIR \b  *-1`) do "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe" a -tzip d:/outputzipfiles/   -o"%~na"
```

I know the above command is wrong, as it must have be like something  -tzip d:\outputzipfiles\knomBk-*.zip, but I do not know how to do it.

I also tried some combinations using the `forfiles` command but no success.

Comment: What does "no success" mean? No zip file, an error message, ...?

Comment: `*`-`1` will not match `knomBk-2.4`.

Comment: Not an error message but  i am unable to get the response i need. I mean when i run D:\test\pk> FOR %a in (`DIR \b  *-1`) do "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe" a -tzip   output.zip   -o"%~na"      i get an output.zip folder at the same location but i want 4 zip files like  {knomBk-2.4.-1.zip, knomBk-2.3-1.zip, knomBk-2.5-1.zip and knomBk-2.6-1.zip} at same location. I know my command is incorrect please let me know how can i get these zip files

Comment: sorry its actually knomBk-2.4-1 it was mistyped by me when i wrote the question now,  i corrected it in my question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my initial test setup (next time, you might want to provide something like this for us).

```
mkdir sotest
cd sotest
mkdir knomBk-2.4-1
mkdir knomBk-2.3-1
mkdir knomBk-2.5-1
mkdir knomBk-2.6-1
echo "oops" > knomBk-2.4-1\a.txt
echo "oops" > knomBk-2.3-1\b.txt
echo "oops" > knomBk-2.5-1\c.txt
echo "oops" > knomBk-2.6-1\d.txt
```

When I need something like you, I do it step by step. By learning this technique, you can solve many problems. It goes like this:

1. Check if `dir \b *-1` works as expected:

   ```
   D:\temp\sotest>dir \b *-1
    Volume in drive D is Mirror
    Volume Serial Number is B693-F1F1

    Directory of D:\

   File Not Found

    Directory of D:\temp\sotest

   05.11.2019  21:47    <DIR>          knomBk-2.3-1
   05.11.2019  21:47    <DIR>          knomBk-2.4-1
   05.11.2019  21:47    <DIR>          knomBk-2.5-1
   05.11.2019  21:47    <DIR>          knomBk-2.6-1
                  0 File(s)              0 bytes
                  4 Dir(s)  2.945.857.200.128 bytes free
   ```

   Answer: no, it doesn't. Correct is `dir /b *-1` with a forward slash
2. Check if the for loop works:

   ```
   D:\temp\sotest>for %a in (`dir /b *-1`) do echo %a

   D:\temp\sotest>echo `dir
   `dir

   D:\temp\sotest>echo /b
   /b
   ```

   Answer: no, it doesn't. Correct is `for /F %a in ('dir /b *-1') do echo %a` with `/F` as an argument and straight apostrophes.
3. Check if my needed arguments (like `%~na`) work:

   ```
   D:\temp\sotest>for /F %a in ('dir /b *-1') do echo "%~na"

   D:\temp\sotest>echo "knomBk-2"
   "knomBk-2"

   D:\temp\sotest>echo "knomBk-2"
   "knomBk-2"

   D:\temp\sotest>echo "knomBk-2"
   "knomBk-2"

   D:\temp\sotest>echo "knomBk-2"
   "knomBk-2"
   ```

   Answer: no, it doesn't. The `~n` part interprets the `.3-1` part as a file extension, which is not expected. Just use `"%a"` instead.
4. Check if the command without the for loop works:

   ```
   D:\temp\sotest>"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "d:/temp/sotest/" -o"x"
   ```

   Answer: no, it doesn't. The file name is not correct and the resulting zip file includes all directories instead of just one. Slashes are in wrong direction. The correct command is `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip -o"d:\temp\sotest\" "x" knomBk-2.3-1/*` with `-o` in the correct place and the directory name to be added.
5. Finally, combine everything:

   ```
   for /F %a in ('dir /b *-1' ) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip -o"d:\temp\sotest\" "%a.zip" "%a/*"
   ```